# Spring Webflow prevent user from going back to the start of the flow after flow completes

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Spring Webflow prevent user from going back to the start of the flow after flow completes and the user is taken to an end state. Clicking the browser back button should take him to an error page and not to the start of the flow. Let me know if i can provide any further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reentering a flow after a user clicks the back button you need some type of condition check or to trigger an exception where either can be caught and handled to redirect to desired page.

**Possible Solutions:**

**1.**  Add to the user's session a variable that indicates a particular flow can no longer be entered by the user and check for this variable at the start of the flow.

```
      <decision-state id="checkBackButtonClick">
        <if test="externalContext.sessionMap.preventBackButtonClick" then="redirectToHomePage" else="continueToEditState"/>
      </decision-state> 

....

      <end-state id="end" view="externalRedirect:/pojos/#{somePojo.id}">
           <on-entry>
                <set name="externalContext.sessionMap.preventBackButtonClick" value="true" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>

            </on-entry>
      </end-state>
```

Although, the solution above appears to be a "hack" I think it is a good solution if you only need this behavior for a 1 or a few flows and it does not require much to implement... (no extending classes, overriding methods, etc...)

**2.** Another possible solution is to place a 'require=true' attribute/value on a input parameter for a flow.

```
<input name="id" required="true"/>
```

So if the user clicks back button without the required param in the url the flow will trigger an exception

```
org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowInputMappingException:
```

And depending on how you handle exceptions in your webflows... you can catch this exception and redirect to your desired page/flow. Assumes you have 'input' tag params.

**3.**  Implement your flow by extending AbstractFlowHandler in java which will give you a tremendous amount of customization power. Obviously 3rd option comes with more coding/work. Use it as a last resort

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-web-flow-webapp-code-example.html

ftp://courses.rvrjcce.ac.in/Java%20Sessions/Software/spring-webflow-2.1.1.RELEASE/docs/spring-webflow-reference/html/ch11s04.html

http://www.jonathanhui.com/spring-web-flow-flow-programming

Comment: the history='invalidate' option seems to be only available on a transition tag under a 'view-state'. In my case, i am going from a <view-state> -> <action-state> -> <end-state>. Once i am in the end state, i do not want a back browser click to take me back to the start of the flow.

Comment: @user1187958 hmm I have not done this in a while. I think what you want to do is trigger an exception any time the back button is triggered and then handle the exception to redirect to the page you desire... or maybe perform a validation check every time the flow begins (and if parameters are missing) and trigger a redirect there. I'm gonna experiment along these lines and see what I come up with

Comment: @user1187958 I updated the answer with my investigation. I couldn't find anything built in but depending on your use case the solutions above will be simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks! I set values in the session to prevent the backbutton. Thanks a lot for your effort!